# Access Denied Error Change Item order - Links List

Tags: list

I am getting error 'Accessed Denied' when i try to reorder links using Change Item order button. It only allows to change the order of links if the user is site collection administrator.
Can someone please help.

Comment: do you think you have sufficient rights? Or in other words: Do you have the right to edit item? (there are plenty of right to have or not)

Comment: I am site collection administrator and i am trying to give permissions to member of a group. I tried to give all permissions levels to the members including full control, combination of design and contribute. The change item order button appears but they are unable to edit order of the links.

Comment: 'Change Item order' link might be reading the permission level of "Edit Items" of a List. So giving the default Full control permission would be enough for your members. Please try that out.

Comment: Full permissions granted to memebers of a group but when they click on Change Item order it showing Error:Access Denied.

Comment: got it resolved. please check this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/9510de0c-2052-47ef-9e5b-d724008ee99b

Comment: @nish, If you have resolved the issue, plz mark correct answer